# Adding dividers after link anchors

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add a span after each of the anchor tags, here is the html:

```
<div class="region-links">
<a href="#" data-slide="0">Okavango Delta</a><span class="rl-line"></span><a href="#" data-slide="1">Moremi</a><span class="rl-line"></span>
<a href="#" data-slide="2">Linyanti</a><span class="rl-line"></span>
<a href="#" data-slide="3">Chobe</a><span class="rl-line"></span>
<a href="#" data-slide="4">Kalahari</a><span class="rl-line">
</span>
<a href="#" data-slide="5">Makgadikgadi</a>     
</div>

.region-links{
  margin: 40px 0;
}

.region-links a{
  color: #801416;
  margin: 0px 6px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 46px;
  display: inline;
  padding: 23px 0;
}

.region-links a:hover{
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.rl-line{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  display: block;
  height: 14px;
  margin-top: -7px;
  width: 1px;
  background: #801416;
}
```

I am just not sure on how to apply them as an :after tag. The reason they need to be an :after tag is because the menu is dynamic

Comment: `:after` is a psuedo-element. It doesn't exist in your markup... Why not just use the `:after` pseudo-element of the `<a>` tags and avoid markup bloat entirely?

Comment: do you have jquery included in your page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that with the `:after` pseudo selector as mentioned in the comments.

```css
.region-links{
  margin: 40px 0;
}

.region-links a{
  color: #801416;
  margin: 0px 6px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 46px;
  display: inline;
  padding: 0 15px 0 15px;
  position: relative;
  
}

.region-links a:hover{
  text-decoration: underline;
}



.region-links a:not(:last-of-type):after { /* Leaves out the last one */
  content: '/'; /* Can be either | or / */
  position: absolute;
  right: -12px; /* Adjust as needed */
  }
```

```html
<div class="region-links">
<a href="#" data-slide="0">Okavango Delta</a><span class="rl-line"></span><a href="#" data-slide="1">Moremi</a><span class="rl-line"></span>
<a href="#" data-slide="2">Linyanti</a><span class="rl-line"></span>
<a href="#" data-slide="3">Chobe</a><span class="rl-line"></span>
<a href="#" data-slide="4">Kalahari</a><span class="rl-line">
</span>
<a href="#" data-slide="5">Makgadikgadi</a>     
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
.region-links a::after{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  ...
}
```